# Retrieve the value from the array and then add it to the new PHP

Tags: php, arrays

i have big problem, because i don't know how get values from this array where value is be key into new array. This is my source array

```
Array
(
     [0] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 250602
            [NAME] => qwe
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 250603
            [NAME] => wer
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 250629
            [NAME] => sdf
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 250629
            [NAME] => xcv
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 250629
            [NAME] => fghfgh
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 250601
            [NAME] => pggd
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 250601
            [NAME] => dfgdfg
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 250606
            [NAME] => dfgdfg
        )
)
```

When id is the same it will be created a new table that will look like for id = 250629

```
[NAME] => Array
        (
            [0] => sdf
            [1] => xcv
            [2] => fghfgh
        )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about foreach loop like this?

```
<?php
$final_array=array();
foreach($arrays as $sub_arr){ //it will traverse loop for all sub-arrays
    $final_array[$sub_arr['ID']][]=$sub_arr['NAME'];       
}
print_r($final_array); //you should see expected output.
?>
```

It will product below output for your given data:

```
Array
(
    [250602] => Array
        (
            [0] => qwe
        )

    [250603] => Array
        (
            [0] => wer
        )

    [250629] => Array
        (
            [0] => sdf
            [1] => xcv
            [2] => fghfgh
        )

    [250601] => Array
        (
            [0] => pggd
            [1] => dfgdfg
        )

    [250606] => Array
        (
            [0] => dfgdfg
        )

)
```

[Working Demo](http://codepad.org/HXMmdHU0)

Comment: Glad to see how my answer helped you figure it out ;)

Comment: That was a small misunderstanding before posting my answer, thanks btw :)

Answer (score 1):

Like this

```
$by_name = array();
foreach($your_array as $item)
    $by_name[$item['ID']] []= $item['name'];
```

This makes use of php's lazy array initialization (`[]=` creates a new array implicitly).

If you get your array from mysql, you might also consider [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat).